# Vue: Data not loading after fetching

Tags: vue.js

I am unable to load data after performing a fetch request. Here's my code,

```
<template>
    <ion-page>
        <ion-header>
            <ion-toolbar>
                <ion-title>Tab 2</ion-title>
            </ion-toolbar>
        </ion-header>
        <ion-content :fullscreen="true">
            {{ console.log(movieData) }}
            <ion-grid>
                <ion-row>
                    <ion-col size="6">
                        <ion-img></ion-img>
                    </ion-col>
                </ion-row>
            </ion-grid>
        </ion-content>
    </ion-page>
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
import { IonPage, IonHeader, IonToolbar, IonTitle, IonContent, IonGrid, IonRow, IonCol, IonImg } from '@ionic/vue';
import { ref } from 'vue';

const movieData = ref(null);

const fetchData = async () => {
    movieData.value = null;
    try {
        const res = await fetch('https://www.eventcinemas.com.au/Movies/GetNowShowing');
        movieData.value = await res.json();
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
    }
};

fetchData();
</script>
```

I suspect that I have to wait for it to mount before performing the function call for `fetchData`?

Comment: I got CORS error with your API: https://www.eventcinemas.com.au/Movies/GetNowShowing . 
When I changed following code `{{ console.log(movieData) }}` to `{{ movieData }}` and consumed another API (https://httpbin.org/get) It worked.

Answer (score 1):

1. Check your network tab if the request was successful
2. Add console.log after you fetched the data and converted to json so you can see if the conversion was successful
3. There is no point in using console.log inside your template. Vue template can't execute this kind of js. Change it to `{{ movieData }}`

Comment: Okay so the reason why the request was failing was due to CORS error, in which I had to disable CORS on my browser. And thanks for the 3rd tip too :)

Answer (score 0):

```js
<script setup>
import { onMounted, ref } from 'vue';

const movieData = ref(null);

const fetchData = async () => {
  try {
    const res = await fetch('https://www.eventcinemas.com.au/Movies/GetNowShowing');
    if (!res.ok) {
      throw new Error(`HTTP error! status: ${res.status}`);
    }
    movieData.value = await res.json();
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('There was a problem fetching the movie data:', error);
  }
};

onMounted(() => {
  fetchData();
});
</script>
```

In this updated code, fetchData is called inside onMounted, which ensures that the component is fully mounted before attempting to load the data. This can help prevent issues if your data fetching relies on the DOM or other mounted-dependent factors. Additionally, the check for res.ok helps catch any non-200 HTTP responses.